# Using Websocket with express and Nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, express, http, websocket

I have this code which I am using for my express server. The server works when I access the routes over http however when I try to connect to it over wss it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

```
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const localStrategy = require("./auth/local");
const jwtStrategy = require("./auth/jwt");
const expressValidator = require("express-validator");
const config = require("./config");

const app = express();

const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.use(localStrategy);
passport.use(jwtStrategy);

require("./routes")(app);

io.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected", socket);
});

http.listen(config.port);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: You can look at this [example](https://socket.io/get-started/chat#integrating-socketio), it uses a slightly different pattern. But the problem might also be on your client side.

Comment: I am using this website to test it. https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ws:` in place of `wss:` for a quick fix.

`wss:` is the TLS-secured version of `ws:`, analogous to `https:` and `http:`. In fact, websocket connections to a server begin their lives as http / https connections. They're then "upgraded" to websocket connections by the websocket protocol.

So, to get `wss:` to work on that server of yours, start by getting `https:` working for the express webserver part. It's the https server behind express that will also handle the connections to be upgraded.